# Metro stations selection module

Tags: web-apps, library, maps, django

Could you please prompt me a module for a site that allow selection of metro station in a form? So when a user selects city in one field, another field displays drop-down list of metro stations in this city (if any). In ideal, it should show graphic map with selection of crossing stations together:

[image]

We already use nginx geoip module and an open countries-cities database. Only a database of metro stations and/or cities districts could be also useful but would solve only a half of the problem.